decreasing stepmoveid gives expected result but also warning
This is a follow-up question to xskak's pastfen and nextfen do not appear to work where Ulrike provided the answer in the comments. The following minimal working example gives the desired output, but also gives the warning
Package xskak Warning: Move number below 1! on Input line 11.

It however does not appear to move below 1 as it correctly prints the desired board.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.e4 c5}

\xskakset{lastmoveid}
\chessboard[setfen=\xskakget{pastfen}]

\xskakset{stepmoveid=-1}
After \xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{san}

\mainline{2.Nf3}

\chessboard
\end{document}


looks like a bug, open an issue at the repo.
